# Improve PHP script execution

Tags: php

I have created script to read text from PDF files. I have around 10000 files, and to read all these file, it can take up to 2 hours. The maximum time out & idle time out for sever is 30 minutes. How can I improve this script or any other solution, so I don't have to change idle time out and the script will be executed in one go.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"The maximum time out for sever is 30 minutes"` - No process can run on the server for more than 30 minutes?  You might want to look into a new server.  As for the question being asked, how can we possibly know?  If the operation takes 2 hours, then it takes 2 hours.  If there are unnecessary bottlenecks you can address, then address them.  We don't know what your code is doing.

Comment: You can read the specific area of the pdf from the script. For example you have a pdf with 1000 lines but you only need data from line 200 to 500 so reading specific area from script might help.

Comment: Way too broad. You are literally asking people to optimize your (non existent) code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP script to handle only one file. Then, create a batch file to execute the php script in loop.

Pseudo code for PHP script:-

1. Get next unread file's path
2. If no more file then exit with code '1'
3. Read file
4. Process file
5. Exit with code '0'

Pseudo code for batch file:-

1. begin
2. run php script
3. if return code for (2) is '0' then go to begin

This will reduce the per script execution time and hence prevent hitting the 30 min limit.

Hope this helps.

[Edit 1]
You batch file should be something like this,

```
@echo off

:Begin
php -f yourscript.php

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO Begin

:End
echo Finished.
```

[Edit 2] Alternate solution for batch file.

Appending a refresh header to the PHP script,

```
header('refresh: 3');
```

to make it self repeating.

Comment: ...what if it returns `1`? What is the expected behaviour of the batch file? Does it just hang....?

Comment: Thanks. I found other solution using header( "refresh:3;url=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

Comment: The return code is just for the application (php.exe) to inform the caller (batch file) about the result. It won't cause any harm. In this case you might use `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` in your php script and use ERRORLEVEL in batch file to check for the result.

Comment: @Sanky Grats you found a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the script execution time using the `set_time_limit()` function.

```
// To disable the time limit
set_time_limit(0);

// To raise the time limit
// The numbe represents the time in seconds
set_time_limit(3600);
```

A second option would be to run your script multiple times with smaller amounts of pdfs.

#### Resuurces

- [set_time_limit() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: As I am using IIS server, I can change the time limit, but not the idle timeout.

Comment: @Sanky: IIS?  Why are you running a *two hour process* on a web server?  That seems like the wrong tool for the job in the first place.

Comment: @Sanky Check my updated answer.

Comment: That already has been in my mind. But I want my script to run in one time.